# Jquery versão a dar problemas

Tags: jquery

Estou com problemas pois o meu site esta feito com Jquery 1.4.1.min e quando chamo um script assim:

```
<select  class="styledselect_pages" onchange="mudalinhas(this.value) ">
```

o Script com esta versão de jquery não funciona:

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Mas com esta versão já funciona :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

O problema desta versão é que se eu a usar no meu site altera me css's do site

Ou seja a minha duvida é como é que posso usar uma destas versões que faça funcionar o meu script e que não mude os meus estilos css.

**O meu script :**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mudalinhas(idlinhas) {
        if (idlinhas == 5) {
            alert("ola");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: O script que colocaste é independente da versão do jQuery, na verdade nada de jQuery é utilizado nessas linhas. Duas perguntas: `#1`: Porque não fazes upgrade no código para poder usar uma versão mais recente do jQuery? `#2` que código mais corre nessa função caso não possas __mesmo__ fazer upgrade do jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar o noConflict do jQuery. Segue abaixo um exemplo.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQ = jQuery.noConflict();
    //Caso a sua classe styledselect_pages seja usada para instânciar algum plugin instâncie com o exemplo abaixo.

    jQ('.styledselect_pages').nome_do_plugin(); // jQ é usada para referenciar o jquery que você usou o noConflict;

    function mudalinhas(idlinhas) {
        if (idlinhas == 5) {
            alert("ola");
        }
    }
</script>
```

> Para mais informações https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/